# Run NSRunLoop in a Cocoa command-line program

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is it possible to initialize a `NSRunLoop` without loading any NIB files (i.e., without calling `NSApplicationMain()`)?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want a run loop in a CLI app?

Comment: why do you want to load nib files in a cli app?

Comment: bertolami: I think he meant *without*.

Comment: @KennyTM: One reason one might want to do this is to use functionality such as CoreLocation (among various others) that requires a run loop to function, but doesn't inherently have any GUI needs.

Comment: @KennyTM - he may want to do something like make a `NSURLConnection` in `main`. Without any special handling, he could exit `main` before the program *really* completes due to delegates being invoked.

Comment: You can also use CFRunLoop

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes; you can write your own main method and run `NSRunLoop` without returning from `NSApplicationMain`.

Have a look at this [link](http://web.archive.org/web/20100208054144/http://chrisalvares.com/blog/?p=7); this guy is using NSRunLoop in his main method, he is not loading NIB files though, but it should get you going with `NSRunloops`.

Comment: See also: the official [NSRunLoop documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSRunLoop_Class)

Answer (score 15):

The solution is to invoke NSApplication manually. Create your app delegate first than replace the NSApplicationMain() call in main.m with the following:

```
AppDelegate * delegate = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];

NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

NSApplication * application = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
[application setDelegate:delegate];
[NSApp run];

[pool drain];

[delegate release];
```

The delegate will be invoked when ready, without needing a nib

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
```

Comment: There's no reason one necessarily needs to use NSApplication (and thus introduce a dependency on AppKit); this can all be done with NSRunLoop.  As such, while this is potentially useful information for someone, I think it's an inappropriate answer to this question.  Down-voting for that reason.

Comment: I was using [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run]; in my GUI-less application, but my application was going into not responding state. This method is working fine for me.

Comment: For ARC, remove [delegate release], [pool drain] and the NSAutoreleasePool, and put @autoreleasepool { } around all of the code.

Answer (score 15):

In Swift, you can achieve this by appending the following line to the end of your `main.swift`:

```
NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().run();  // Swift < 3.0
RunLoop.current.run();             // Swift >= 3.0
```

If you want to be able to stop the run loop you have to use the Core Foundation methods.

```
CFRunLoopRun(); // start
```

And you can stop it like this

```
CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent()); // stop
```

Comment: This is great... now I don't know how to stop, though. Do you have any suggestions for me?

Answer (score 9):

Follow the recommendations in the docs for [NSRunLoop run]:

```
BOOL shouldKeepRunning = YES;        // global
NSRunLoop *theRL = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
while (shouldKeepRunning && [theRL runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate     distantFuture]]);
```

Comment: some more explanation is due - when I try it, the while() never exits before the end-date (and when that's set to distantFuture - it just never exists to check the shouldKeepRunning). I tried to remove everything from the runloop, to no avail. CFRunnLoopStop() crashes, and.... well... more explanation is due. this doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Hi, are you setting shouldKeepRunning = NO at some point in something that has been scheduled on your runloop? You must schedule things on the runloop before entering this while loop as well. Good luck!

Answer (score 8):

```
// Yes.  Here is sample code (tested on OS X 10.8.4, command-line).
// Using ARC:
// $ cc -o timer timer.m -fobjc-arc -framework Foundation
// $ ./timer
//

#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property NSTimer *timer;
-(id)init;
-(void)onTick:(NSTimer *)aTimer;
@end

@implementation MyClass
-(id)init {
    id newInstance = [super init];
    if (newInstance) {
        NSLog(@"Creating timer...");
        _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
            target:self
            selector:@selector(onTick:)
            userInfo:nil
            repeats:YES];
    }
    return newInstance;
}

-(void)onTick:(NSTimer *)aTimer {
    NSLog(@"Tick");
}
@end

int main() {
    @autoreleasepool {
        MyClass *obj = [[MyClass alloc] init];
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at asynctask.m that runs an NSRunLoop manually 
to enable the use of asynchronous "waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify" notifications.

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSPipe

```
  NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

   while(!terminated) 
   {
     //if (![[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:100000]])
     if (![[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]]) 
     {
         break;
     }
      [pool release];
      pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
   }

   [pool release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take using only DispatchQueue. Most command line tools want to exit with a status. The background dispatch queue is concurrent.

```
import Foundation

var exitStatus: Int32 = 0

let background = DispatchQueue(label: "commandline", qos: .userInteractive, attributes: [], autoreleaseFrequency: .workItem)

background.async {
    var ii = 1
    while ii < CommandLine.arguments.count {
        
        process(file:CommandLine.arguments[ii])
        ii += 1
    }
}
background.async {
    exit(exitStatus)
}
RunLoop.current.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a CLI app and I needed to run a runLoop to let NSWorkspace class works right and also to get notifications from NSWorkspace.
I made it thanks this discussion, but I don't understand why most of the answers suggest to use a NSTimer so I would like to share my solution without it.

Because [NSRunLoop run] "blocks" the thread and also my CLI logic blocks the thread by waiting for stdin, in the main function I create a thread for my CLI app logic, then I runned the NSRunLoop:

```objectivec
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
  NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];

  pthread_t thread;
  // current NSRunLoop passed to the thread
  err = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, run_thread, runLoop);
  if (err != 0) {
    return err;
  }

  [runLoop run];
  [pool release];
  
  // I'm not able to stop the NSRunLoop even with CFRunLoopStop
  // so you probably never reach this point.
  // However, for safety, here I wrote code for handling pthread_join

  return 0;
}
```

Then in my thread I do my CLI logic and, when I need to access to NSWorkspace API (that needs the NSRunLoop to work) I use the `performBlock:` method on NSRunLoop:

```objectivec
void *run_thread(void *data) {
  NSRunLoop *runLoop = (NSRunLoop *)data;
  FILE *input = stdin;
  FILE *output = stdout;

  // my CLI code that read from stdio
  // while (1) {
  //   fread( ... );
  //   ...

  // then, when I need, I schedule code to the NSRunLoop
  [runLoop performBlock:^{
    // call API that need the main runLoop to work
    // [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserverForName: ...];
    // ...
  }];

  // to stop the runLoop so the application I call exit inside the runLoop
  [runLoop performBlock:^{
    exit(0);
  }];

  // ...
}
```

To be more accurate I decided to read data (input) from my thread and work with output in the runLoop so to not have concurrency on resources.