# objective-c, web service framework for a command line project

Tags: objective-c, macos, web-services, command-line

I'm working on the script in objective-c.
I created a "Command Line Tool" in xcode and I want to request a JSON web service.

In my previous iPhone apps I use to import ASIHTTPRequest framework. Unfortunetly this framework use UIKit library.

I don't want to import this library and all these dependencies.

Do you know a good framework or library that I can use in my Command Line Tool application ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASIHTTPRequest shouldn't require UIKit. You should be able to remove that if it's there. You can't import UIKit into a Mac app anyway.

The ASI framework has been discontinued, though. You may want to look at other options such as [MKNetworkKit](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit) and [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). Both should work fine in a commandline app.

---

EDIT: Don't forget that most frameworks like this will require a run loop. The typical way to manage that in a commandline app looks like this (from [NSRunLoop](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSRunLoop_Class/Reference/Reference.html) docs):

```
BOOL shouldKeepRunning = YES;        // global
NSRunLoop *theRL = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
while (shouldKeepRunning && [theRL runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]]);
```

This is an infinite loop until something sets `shouldKeepRunning`.

You can also use `NSApplication` as shown in [Run NSRunLoop in a Cocoa command-line program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154600/command-line-cocoa-app-no-gui).

Comment: Thanks for the advice.
So I tried AFNetworking. I installed it successfully in my project after removing files using NSImage that cause a compilation error.

Unfortunetly for the moment I can't get my web service request working. I followed the document example withouh success.

But no log is written (success ou failure). So I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how to put my code here properly.
All the code is on the same line so it's unreadable.

Comment: ace, I've been looking for this run loop stuff

Comment: calling dispatch_main is often a better way to run the infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASIHTTPRequest in a command line tool.

For an example feel free to look at my `pinch-objc` project available at github. See the `zipcommander` project.

https://github.com/epatel/pinch-objc