# Trouble with NSTimer

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I am having so much trouble with NSTimers.  I have used them before, but this timer just does not want to fire.

```
-(void) enqueueRecordingProcess
{
    NSLog(@"made it!");
    NSTimer *time2 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(warnForRecording) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

-(void) warnForRecording
{
    NSLog(@"timer ticked!");
    if (trv > 0) {
        NSLog(@"Starting Recording in %i seconds.", trv);
    }
}
```

I don't see why this won't run.  I even tried this:

```
- (void)enqueueRecordingProcess
{
    NSLog(@"made it!");
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(warnForRecording) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

 - (void)warnForRecording
{
    NSLog(@"timer ticked!");
}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this fixes it but from the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html):

```
The message to send to target when the timer fires. The selector must have the following signature:
- (void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer*)theTimer
The timer passes itself as the argument to this method.
```

Comment: I tried this as well.  It still is not running.  The only way I can make it run is using [timer fire], but that only makes it run once.

Comment: @rbvcode are you running this via a command line app or through a Cocoa app? NSTimer won't work in a Command line app because there is no runloop.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII ok... that explains it. Thank you so much. Nobody explained to me that their is no run loop in a Command line app.  I will need to process my app in a completely different way.  Sorry for not knowing this. This is the first time that I have ever developed a command line app that needed a timer. Once again, Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: To run the run loop, you can just call [[NSRunLoop runloop] run] or something like that at the end of main.

Comment: Re: using the run loop in a command line program: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154600/command-line-cocoa-app-no-gui

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about you specifics, but you need to service the runloop in order to get events, including timers.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Yes.  Here is sample code (tested on OS X 10.8.4, command-line).
// Using ARC:
// $ cc -o timer timer.m -fobjc-arc -framework Foundation
// $ ./timer
//

#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property NSTimer *timer;
-(id)init;
-(void)onTick:(NSTimer *)aTimer;
@end

@implementation MyClass
-(id)init {
    id newInstance = [super init];
    if (newInstance) {
        NSLog(@"Creating timer...");
        _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
            target:self
            selector:@selector(onTick:)
            userInfo:nil
            repeats:YES];
    }
    return newInstance;
}

-(void)onTick:(NSTimer *)aTimer {
    NSLog(@"Tick");
}
@end

int main() {
    @autoreleasepool {
        MyClass *obj = [[MyClass alloc] init];
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
    }
    return 0;
}
```