# NSTimer in command line tool

Tags: objective-c, concurrency, nstimer, core-bluetooth, command-line-tool

I'm getting to know the NS/Objective-C model of concurrency. Say I have a command line tool that does something like this:

```
#include "myLibrary.h"

void callback(void* parameter){
  cout<<"callback called.\n";
  //some logic...
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  myLibraryInit(callback);
  std::string s;
  while(true){
    cin>>s;
    myLibrarysResponseTo(s);
  }
}
```

In my library, I'd like to be able to have two responses. One which starts a repeating timer and one which stops it. The timer should call the callback supplied to the library by myLibraryInit.

I've used NSTimers before in iPhone/iPad apps, and I think the problem stems from the different paradigm command line tools have. The main thread goes into main and never finishes it until the program is finished. This means it's not free to run the main run loop, which is what gets the timer going. I think. So how do I make an NSTimer work in this context?

The other thing is that Apple NSTimer documentation says I need to invalidate an NSTimer on the same *thread* it was installed. I don't know how to figure out what thread I was on when I installed the timer, and then keep track of it (and ensure it stays alive) until I want to invalidate the timer. I'm not sure if I'm just missing an obvious mapping between threads and dispatch queues, run loops, or something else. I am using core bluetooth and I initialize a central manager like so:

```
_centralManager=[[CBCentralManager alloc]
  initWithDelegate: self
  queue: dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
];
```

so a callback may be triggered from here. If the callback includes some logic to call the library function that stops the timer, I can't guarantee from which thread came the invalidate. So how do I properly invalidate the timer?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154600/run-nsrunloop-in-a-cocoa-command-line-program) question but it doesn't allow a main to happen at the same time as the run loop that that the timer is on.

I hope I gave enough context. Thanks in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 7):

You must call `dispatch_main()` or run an `NSRunLoop` in the main thread if any of the system frameworks [that use GCD or asynchronous operations] are to work correctly.

This can be as simple as calling `[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];` at the end of your `main()` function (just make sure you schedule the kickoff work first as that method never returns).

Comment: This would be a considerable shift in paradigm for all (including non-Mac) users of the library. Is there any other way? A good alternative to NSTimer?

Comment: @CodeSoda You'll have to keep the library isolated in threads other than the main thread, then.   The key is to *not block threads* that  are being used by GCD or by NSRunLoop.  That means that any time you want to use the System APIs from your library, you'll want to do that in some *other* thread than the library's thread(s).

Comment: So, can I just get a sanity check on how I want to do this?
1) subclass NSThead.
1a) In the main, schedule a timer that calls an intermediate member function; then run the current run loop.
1b) In the intermediate member function, check if the thread is canceled. If yes, exit, else call the function I'm interested in calling repeatedly.
2) To start doing something repeatedly: allocate, init, and start a subclassed thread.
3) To stop doing that thing repeatedly: cancel the thread.

Comment: thank you! i was so stuck on this trying to export a video with AVFoundation, the completion callback that finishes the export process wasn't getting called. Adding dispatch_main() on main.swift fixed it perfectly!