# Async request does not enter completion block

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, asynchronous

The following code is an attempt to me better understand `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler]`.

There are `NSLog` statements in the `completionHandler` block, but when I run this in `main.m` in XCode from a command line project, it never enters the `completionHandler` blocks. I've tried using the different queues, `mainQueue` and `currentQueue` but neither work.

My hunch is that the queue is being deallocated before the request is completed and that retain cycles are involved.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSCache *myCache = [[NSCache alloc] init];

        NSArray *images = @[
         @"https://i.stack.imgur.com/E66qr.png",
         @"http://www.tiempoyquimera.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/Euro-Trash-Girl-2010.jpg",
         @"http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Mxd8AB2nbQY/UYCISJiQz3I/AAAAAAAAAH8/Tc43U8aa9dM/s1600/Tarantino10colhans_1460858i.jpg",
         @"https://awestruckwanderer.files.wordpress.com/2014/02/alan-watts.png",
         @"http://www.esalen.org/sites/default/files/photo_images/20120201_DELLIS__MG_9612_711.jpg"];

        for (NSString *image in images){
            NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:image];
            NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:myURL];

            NSLog(@"Can handle request %@", @([NSURLConnection canHandleRequest:request]));
            NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];

            [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                               queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                   completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                                       NSLog(@"In the completion handler");
                                       if (!error)
                                       {
                                           // save data to cache with url as key
                                           NSLog(@"Image Added to Cache");
                                           [myCache setObject:data
                                                       forKey:myURL];
                                       } else
                                       {
                                           NSLog(@"Image Not Added to Cache");
                                       }
                                   }];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My hunch is that the queue is being deallocated before the request is completed and that retain cycles are involved

Not quite. Retain cycles are not involved. Persistence is involved. You are doing this in a `main` function. It exits *immediately* - the asynchronous stuff (the networking and the subsequent callback) is asynchronous, so it would come later, *if* we had any persistence. But we don't. `main` exits, and that means that the *whole darned program* is torn down, **kaboom**, before there is any opportunity to do any networking, let alone call back into the completion handler after the networking.

Now contrast this with how things happen in real life. In a real iOS app, `main` does *not* exit, because it calls `UIApplicationMain`, which loops until the app is terminated.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil,
            NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

In that code, `UIApplicationMain` just keeps running until it is aborted or otherwise terminated. Meanwhile, classes and instance have sprung to life, and they persist, because `UIApplicationMain` does not stop. For example:

```
@implementation MyViewController
- (void) someMethod {
    // ...
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
         queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
         completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
             // ...
    }
}
@end
```

Now, in one sense, exactly the same thing happens: `someMethod` exits immediately. But our program overall is still running! `UIApplicationMain` has a run loop and that run loop is still cycling. Thus, things live on, and so now the asynchronous material can happen - we can network and then call the callback.

Comment: Is there a scenario where `main` persists for long enough for one of the completion `block`s to be entered, or will `main` always terminate before one of the `blocks` begins.

Comment: You need a run loop. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154600/run-nsrunloop-in-a-cocoa-command-line-program