# Why is a notification not displaying from a swift script?

Tags: swift, nsnotificationcenter

Here is my swift script which runs without errors, however, does nothing. I would expect it to display a notification in the notification center.

```
#!/usr/bin/env swift

import Foundation

let notification = NSUserNotification()
notification.title = "Hello"

let notificationCenter = NSUserNotificationCenter.defaultUserNotificationCenter()

class MyNotificationDelegate: NSObject, NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate
{
    func userNotificationCenter(center: NSUserNotificationCenter,
        shouldPresentNotification notification: NSUserNotification) -> Bool {
            return true
    }
}

notificationCenter.delegate = MyNotificationDelegate()
notificationCenter.deliverNotification(notification)
```

Can someone explain why this code snippet runs as expected from a playground (displays a Notification) but does nothing, when executed as script from a terminal.

Comment: "when executed as script from a terminal" Because the script ends and everything is torn down before the notification has a chance to be delivered to anything.

Comment: That won't "keep it alive" - it just pauses, interrupting the progress of everything (it blocks). Compare my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30825723/341994

Comment: Hmm, this would imply that adding `NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().run()
` should help, doesn't it? Unfortunately this does not help as well.

Comment: are you calling deliver notification before setting the delegate?

Comment: good point, it would make sense to call `deliverNotification` after setting the delegate. However, the script does still not display the notification (edited the example script)