# InstallApplicatonEventHandler/NSNotificationCenter doesnt notify events (NSN)

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, macos, notifications

I want to register for time change notifications in mac os. usng C Api's. I tried the ApplicaitonEventHandler api which seemed to be the api for this case, but I am not getting notified for any events

code shared at,

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a0b3e24e02b844bfb11e2b5d02e47d83

I registered for all possible event but triggering any of the event doesnt seem to create a notificaion for me.

I am using .mm extension as I want my code exposed as a c style api so and if I can interop with a private objective c class if possible (i.e if objective c object can be instantiated inside a c++ method and a suitable objective c api is available for such notifcations).

[Note] Used the NSNotification suggested below, it doesnt send any notifcations either.

Comment: I registered for the nsnotification from the sample cocoa application and the observer is notified as expected.

Is this a limitation for console apps or am I doing something wrong ?
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b7f9f9d0402447c49c59e30f0a6e8977

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to be notified when the clock is changed, you can listen to the com.apple.MenuBarClock.ClockNotification.

```
[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(timeChanged:) name:@"com.apple.MenuBarClock.ClockNotification" object:nil suspensionBehavior:NSNotificationSuspensionBehaviorDeliverImmediately];
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b7f9f9d0402447c49c59e30f0a6e8977

@stefanf  used the NSNotificationCenter, and distributednotification center both doesnt yeild the callback.

Comment: I created a simple application using xcode, IS there anything my console app needs to do to start receiving these notifications ?

Comment: Added an objective-c sample to your gist.

Comment: Thanks for the sample, is there a way to do this without sharedApplication? sharedApplication seems to be singleton and may be shared by other modules in the process. 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622975-sharedapplication?language=objc

Comment: Found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154600/run-nsrunloop-in-a-cocoa-command-line-program