# Use UIWebView in console

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebviewdelegate

I want to use UIWebView in the console, so I define a delegate:

```
@interface webViewDelegate : NSObject <UIWebViewDelegate>
```

and write the protocol:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error;
```

and then loadRequest:

```
webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
webView.delegate = WVdelegate;
NSURL *htmlURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.100"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:htmlURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

The problem is that this is a console, and I want to finish the console after the delegate has been invoked. What should I do to wait for the delegate after calling `loadRequest`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "in console"?

Comment: What do you mean by "finish the console" ? You want to remove the Webview?

Comment: sorry ,my program is a command line tool ,so after call [webView loadRequest:request],the program is over 。i just want to get the result in - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView.  so  i think i should add  do something after call [webView loadRequest:request].

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have no runloop. Thus, when your code comes to an end, the command-line tool comes to an end; things do not persist long enough for the asynchronous code to run.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154600/run-nsrunloop-in-a-cocoa-command-line-program

Answer (score 0):

You can get HTML source in console:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView 
{
    // Check here if still webview is loding the content
    if (webView.isLoading)
        return;

    NSString *fullHtml = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML"];
    NSLog(@"html:%@", fullHtml);
}
```

Comment: yes ,i just do it ,but after call [webView loadRequest:request],the command line tool is over, so how can i wait for webViewDidFinishLoad is invoked?I am try to do this : [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5];  but it's invalid.