# How to use combine Timer.publish(…) in Command Line Tool Application with RunLoop.current...?

Tags: swift, xcode

If I write the following code in a command line tool app, nothing happens.

Someone could help me to understand why and how to do?

Thanks in advance.

```
let subscription = Timer.publish(every: 1.0, on: .main, in: .default)
    .autoconnect()
    .sink { _ in
        print("timer fired")
    }
```

How RunLoop can solve that?

Comment: This doesn't resolve my problem. Or maybe I don't understand how.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28912455/8697793

Comment: Yes, it does. Your code is asynchronous. You are a command line tool. Therefore you need a run loop.